# onNavigationItemSelected vs onNavigationDrawerItemSelected in Navigation Drawer

Tags: android

When to use a method of `onNavigationItemSelected` and `onNavigationDrawerItemSelected` in the template `NavigationDrawer` ? I don't know which method to choose for my app on `Material Design`.

Comment: A suggestion: If you want to implement the custom one, try this : https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer . This is simple and easy to implement.

Comment: Great advice! I am very grateful!